# How to get current month's 1st day value and last month's last day value in every row in a daily table in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following table

| Date | Region | KPI Key | KPI Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2021 | Region1 | 1001 | 1234 |
| 31/01/2021 | Region2 | 1001 | 5678 |
| 31/01/2021 | Region1 | 1002 | 9100 |
| 31/01/2021 | Region2 | 1002 | 1112 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region1 | 1001 | 1314 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region2 | 1001 | 1516 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region1 | 1002 | 1718 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region2 | 1002 | 1920 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region1 | 1001 | 2122 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region2 | 1001 | 2324 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region1 | 1002 | 2526 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region2 | 1002 | 2728 |

I want to have the output table like this:

| Date | Region | KPI Key | KPI Value | KPI Value LM LD | KPI Value CM FD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2021 | Region1 | 1001 | 1234 |  |  |
| 31/01/2021 | Region2 | 1001 | 5678 |  |  |
| 31/01/2021 | Region1 | 1002 | 9100 |  |  |
| 31/01/2021 | Region2 | 1002 | 1112 |  |  |
| 01/02/2021 | Region1 | 1001 | 1314 | 1234 | 1314 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region2 | 1001 | 1516 | 5678 | 1516 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region1 | 1002 | 1718 | 9100 | 1718 |
| 01/02/2021 | Region2 | 1002 | 1920 | 1112 | 1920 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region1 | 1001 | 2122 | 1234 | 1314 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region2 | 1001 | 2324 | 5678 | 1516 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region1 | 1002 | 2526 | 9100 | 1718 |
| 02/02/2021 | Region2 | 1002 | 2728 | 1112 | 1920 |

I used below first_value window function to get the current month's first day value (KPI_VALUE_CM_FD) but struggling to get previous month's last dayy valye (KPI_VALUE_LM_LD).

```
 select a.*, first_value(kpi_value) over(partition by date,region,kpi_key order by date) 
    kpi_value_CM_FD
    from table1
```

Please help me get the previous monthlast day value for each KPI key for each region in each row

Answer (score 0):

The `first_value` doesn't match your description, `partition by date` does not return the *current month's first day value*, you need to `partition by last_day(dt)`. Regarding the previous month:

This should match your expected result:

```
with cte as
 (
   select a.*, 
      -- current month's first day value
      first_value(kpi_value) 
      over(partition by last_day(dt),region,kpi_key
           order by dt) as kpi_value_CM_FD
      -- last day of previous month
     ,max(dt)
      over(partition by last_day(dt),region,kpi_key) as max_dt
   from vt as a
  )
select cte.*
   -- previous month last day value
  ,lag(case when dt = max_dt then kpi_value end ignore nulls)
       over (partition by region,kpi_key
             order by dt) as kpi_value_LM_FD
from cte
```